# Is there a way to see all of the different values in each field?

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes

I'm using QGIS.  I have an attribute table that lists different land classifications under the "Land Type" column (agricultural, industrial, etc.).  I don't know what all the land types are and I would just like to find a list of them instead of scrolling down through thousands of entries. Is there a way to do this?  The metadata table is wrong so I have no documentation to go from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but you could also go to `layer properties --> source --> query builder` and click on `All` for your desired column.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try `Vector => Analysis Tools => List unique values`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe another way:

1. press `Open Field Calculator` button in the "Attributes Toolbar" to open the Field Calculator;
2. find and select your `Land Type` column under `Fields and Values` node in the tree under `Search` textbox, then press `All Unique` button on the right.

Answer (score 3):

To generate a comma separated list of all categories, you can use this expression:

```
concatenate_unique ( "landuse", concatenator:= ', ' )
```

You might want to add a condition like `if ( "id" = 1, [expression], '')` (substitute `[expression]` with the expreesion from above) to create the list only in one row and not in all of them to avoid excessive calculation of repeating values.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use pyqgis, from: [How to find unique values of an attribute with python in qgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73753/how-to-find-unique-values-of-an-attribute-with-python-in-qgis)

```
vectorLayer = iface.activeLayer()
fname = 'kategori'
idx = vectorLayer.fields().indexOf(fname)
values = sorted(vectorLayer.uniqueValues(idx))
print('\n') #Just an empty line
for v in values:
    print(v)
```

[image]